# Nodejs Dados duplicados quando uso Request Api

Tags: node.js

olá,

Sou novo em nodejs! Estou desenvolvendo um codigo que le uma Tabela em postgreSQL e deacordo com o registro executa algumas API GET. 
Por exemplo, se retorna "int" executa "http://api1/param", se retorna "fab" executa "http://api2/param". Depois gravo em outra tabela o retorno das APIs.

Mas estou tendo o seguinte problema, esta executando 2 ou mais vezes a API e gravando no banco. O que não entendo é que não ocorre sempre isso.

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Código:

```
const express = require('express'),
      http = require('http'),
      app = express(),
      server = http.createServer(app),
      schedule = require('node-schedule'),
      dateFormat = require('dateformat'),
      pg = require('pg'),
      request = require('request');

const configPg150 = {
    user: 'xxxxx',
    database: 'xxxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxxx',
    port: xxxxx
};

var pools = new pg.Pool(configPg150)

const { Pool } = require('pg');
const pool = new Pool(configPg150);

const tbNome = "tb1";
const tbNomeN = "tb2";

(async () => {
    const client = await pool.connect()
    try {
        let startTime = new Date(Date.now() + 1000);
        var j = schedule.scheduleJob({ start: startTime, end: null, rule: '*/3 * * * * *' }, function(){
            seleciona(client);
        });
    } finally {
        //client.release()
    }
    await pool.end();
})().catch(e => console.log(e.stack))

async function seleciona(client) {

    agora = new Date(Date.now());
    dt_envioA = dateFormat(agora, "HH:MM:ss");
    console.log("Seleciona - "+dt_envioA);

    const res = await client.query('SELECT * FROM "'+tbNomeN+'" WHERE bloq = 0 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10')
    if (res.rows != undefined)  {
        for(var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
            var myJSONObject = {
                'Id' : res.rows[i].id,
                'MessageTo' : "55"+res.rows[i].ToNo,
                'MessageTo55' : res.rows[i].ToNo,
                'MessageText' : res.rows[i].Message,
                'id_sms' : res.rows[i].id_sms,
                'id_usu' : res.rows[i].id_usu,
                'envio_por': res.rows[i].envio_por
            };
            await verificaEnvio(myJSONObject, client);
        }
    }
}

async function verificaEnvio(arrDados, client) {
    let text = 'SELECT * FROM '+tbNome+' WHERE id_sms = $1 AND numero = $2 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1';
    let values = [arrDados['id_sms'], arrDados['MessageTo55']];
    const resI = client.query(text, values, (err, result) => {
        if (err)
            return console.error('Error executing query', err.stack)

        agora = new Date(Date.now());
        dt_envioA = dateFormat(agora, "HH:MM:ss");
        console.log(dt_envioA + ' ---------- '+arrDados['id_sms']+' - '+arrDados['MessageTo55']+' - '+result.rowCount);

        if (result.rowCount == 0) {
            if (arrDados['envio_por'] == "hot") {
                send3(arrDados, client); 
            } else if (arrDados['envio_por'] == "fab") {
                send2(arrDados, client);
            } else if (arrDados['envio_por'] == "int") {
                send1(arrDados, client);
            } else {
                send1(arrDados, client);
            }
        } else {
            delData(arrDados, client); 
        }

    });
}

async function delData(arrDados, client) {
    agora = new Date(Date.now());
    dt_envioA = dateFormat(agora, "HH:MM:ss");    
    console.log(dt_envioA + ' - DDD DEL: '+arrDados['id_sms']+' - '+arrDados['MessageTo55']);

    agora = new Date(Date.now());
    dt_envio = dateFormat(agora, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss");

    const textD = 'DELETE FROM "'+tbNomeN+'" WHERE "id" = '+arrDados["Id"];
    const valuesD = [];
    const resD = await client.query(textD, valuesD);
}

async function send1(arrDados, client) {

    agora = new Date(Date.now());
    dt_envioA = dateFormat(agora, "HH:MM:ss");
    console.log(dt_envioA + ' - SSS ONE: '+arrDados['id_sms']+' - '+arrDados['MessageTo55']);

    await request({
        url: "http://api.xxxxxxx1.com.br/api/send/simple&token=xxxxxxxx&to="+arrDados['MessageTo']+"&msg="+arrDados["MessageText"],
        method: "GET",
        json: true
    }, function(err,httpResponse,body){
        if (err) { return console.log(err); }
        agora = new Date(Date.now());
        dt_envio = dateFormat(agora, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss");

        const text = 'INSERT INTO "'+tbNome+'" ("ToNo", "Message", "retorno", "dt_envio", "id_sms", "enviado_por", "retorno_txt", "id_usu", "numero") VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9)';
        const values = [arrDados['MessageTo55'], arrDados['MessageText'], body, dt_envio, arrDados['id_sms'], 'ccccc', 'ccccc', arrDados['id_usu'], arrDados['MessageTo55']];
        const resI = client.query(text, values);

        const textD = 'DELETE FROM "'+tbNomeN+'" WHERE "id" = '+arrDados["Id"];
        const valuesD = [];
        const resD = client.query(textD, valuesD);
    });
}

async function send2(arrDados, client) {

    agora = new Date(Date.now());
    dt_envioA = dateFormat(agora, "HH:MM:ss");
    console.log(dt_envioA + ' - MMM FAB: '+arrDados['id_sms']+' - '+arrDados['MessageTo55']);

    await request({
        url: "https://api.xxxxxxxx2.com.br/send.php?username=xxxxxx&password=xxxxxxxx&to="+arrDados['MessageTo']+"&content="+arrDados["MessageText"],
        method: "GET",
        json: true
    }, function(err,httpResponse,body){
        if (err) { return console.log(err); }
        agora = new Date(Date.now());
        dt_envio = dateFormat(agora, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss");

        const text = 'INSERT INTO "'+tbNome+'" ("ToNo", "Message", "retorno", "dt_envio", "id_sms", "enviado_por", "retorno_txt", "id_usu", "numero") VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9)';
        const values = [arrDados['MessageTo55'], arrDados['MessageText'], body, dt_envio, arrDados['id_sms'], 'cccc', 'cccc', arrDados['id_usu'], arrDados['MessageTo55']];
        const resI = client.query(text, values);

        const textD = 'DELETE FROM "'+tbNomeN+'" WHERE "id" = '+arrDados["Id"];
        const valuesD = [];
        const resD = client.query(textD, valuesD);
    });
}

async function send3(arrDados, client) {

    agora = new Date(Date.now());
    dt_envioA = dateFormat(agora, "HH:MM:ss");
    console.log(dt_envioA + ' - XXX HOT: '+arrDados['id_sms']+' - '+arrDados['MessageTo55']);

    var resposta = "";
    await request({
        url: "http://painel.xxxxxxxx3.com.br/SendAPI/Send.aspx?usr=xxxxxxxxx&pwd=xxxxxxxx&number="+arrDados['MessageTo']+"&msg="+arrDados["MessageText"],
        method: "GET",
        json: true
    }, function(err,httpResponse,body){
        if (err) { return console.log(err); }

        agora = new Date(Date.now());
        dt_envio = dateFormat(agora, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss");

        const text = 'INSERT INTO "'+tbNome+'" ("ToNo", "Message", "retorno", "dt_envio", "id_sms", "enviado_por", "retorno_txt", "id_usu", "numero") VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9)';
        const values = [arrDados['MessageTo55'], arrDados['MessageText'], body, dt_envio, arrDados['id_sms'], 'ccccc', 'ccccc', arrDados['id_usu'], arrDados['MessageTo55']];
        const resI = client.query(text, values);

        const textD = 'DELETE FROM "'+tbNomeN+'" WHERE "id" = '+arrDados["Id"];
        const valuesD = [];
        const resD = client.query(textD, valuesD);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, acho que o seu problema esta no seu crontab.
No seu código você faz um agendamento (schedule) para rodar a função seleciona(client).

> let startTime = new Date(Date.now() + 1000);
>           var j = schedule.scheduleJob({ start: startTime, end: null, rule: '*/3 * * * * *' },
>   seleciona(client);

Nesse código você esta pedindo para o cron rodar a função seleciona(client) a cada 3 minutos (rule: '*/3 * * * * *') depois de 1 segundo (start: startTime) e não parar nunca (end: null).
Percebe o problema? Depois que você receber a primeira request na API o seu programa vai ficar executando seleciona(client) a cada 3 minutos.
Para resolver seu problema você deve ver se realmente precisa fazer essa esse agendamento, se precisar então coloque uma condição de parada.

Comment: Obrigado. Mas uma dúvida. Preciso monitorar o banco de dados para verificar se tem registro novo. E processar esse registro de acordo com o código. Existe outra maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Tem outra aplicação fora a API que grava os dados nesse banco? Se não tiver, você não precisa fazer esse monitoramento, você pode utilizar as callback sempre que fizer um insert no banco. Tipo assim, na função que faz o insert coloca uma callback, assim quando terminar o insert ele vai retornar para essa callback e nela você coloca o que deve ser feito com o registro novo. Tem muita informação sobre callback por aí, bem fácil de encontrar.

Comment: Agora, se for realmente necessário essa verificação, eu criaria uma trigger na tabela principal (trigger onInesrt), assim após o insert nessa tabela ela grava o ID novo em uma tabela secundária, (tabela TemRegistroNovo por exemplo). Então no seu código você pode criar um schedule para ficar monitorando essa tabela TemRegistroNovo, se tiver alguma coisa nela ele sabe que foi inserido dado novo na tabela principal, e com o ID ele consegue buscar, depois de ter feito o que precisa deve apagar o conteúdo da tabela TemRegistroNovo, assim você sabe que o único registro lá é sempre informação nova.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!! Ajudou bastante!!!

Comment: Se ajudou marca a resposta como correta para ajudar outras pessoas tbm!!